# Apache Hive String to Datetime conversion

Tags: string, timestamp, hive

I want to convert column which is String in HDFS to convert into Timestamp in Hive table.

String format is YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:xxx in HDFS, but when I define external table with Timestamp column type it is returning Null.

Comment: Can you show your table definition and some sample data?

Comment: CSV files which are ingested in HDFS, first column of csv is of 2015-02-15 18:35:60:234 format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:xxx). In Hive external table datatype of datecolumn  is of Timestamp. but when I offer select command the date column is returning null.

Comment: 2015-02-12 18:19:47:126,ixxxxxxx-rxx-exxxxxxxx,ue-context valid : 401x1,xxx-yyyyy-oo ZZZZZZ99,

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INTYYYY_XXXX(column1 timestamp, column2 varchar(500) ,column3 varchar(500) ,
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'hdfs://109.104.XX.YY:9000/IXXXXXX_IZZZ/'

Answer (score 0):

The Hive `TIMESTAMP` data type requires a `.` between the seconds and milliseconds, instead of a `:`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I will check again after replacing : with .